# Kivy RecycleView. Appending data from another class

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to append data of `RV` from `Newline`. I see that `refresh_view_attrs` works but there is nothing shown on the screen. How can I do it?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    Label:
        id: id_label

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True
''')

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        print('SelectableLabel', data)
        self.ids['id_label'].text = data['label']
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = []

rv = RV()

class Newline(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_line, 3)

    def add_line(self, dt):
        d = {'label': 'NEW LINE'}
        rv.data.append(d)

Newline()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rv = RV()

class Newline(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_line, 3)

    def add_line(self, dt):
        d = {'label': 'NEW LINE'}
        rv.data.append(d)

Newline()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()
```

Your root widget is a `RV()`, and you append data to a *different* `RV()`.

You want to append data to the RV that you're actually displaying: `App.get_running_app().root.data.append(d)` would work.